# From S.D.E to Fokker-Plank-Smoluchowski equation

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

Let me use as reference these lecture notes : [http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~pavl/lecture_notesM4A42.pdf](http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/%7Epavl/lecture_notesM4A42.pdf)  In section 5.4 (page 59) here the author argues how the sample paths for a diffusion (from which they derived the FPS equation) follows a standard S.D.E

- But its not clear to me as to if one can start from a standard S.D.E (as say given in their page 60) one can derive the FPS equation.
- As a specific example : If one sees equation 6.33 (on page 75) this is exactly what they seem to be alluding to be possible : that one can start from the S.D.E ``$dX_t = -\nabla V (X_t)dt + \sqrt{2D}dW_t$" and get the FPS for it as, $\frac{\partial p}{\partial t} = \nabla \cdot (\nabla (V\cdot p)) + D \nabla^2 p$. Can someone kindly refer me to a derivation of this ? (or write it in if that is not too long!)

Answer (score 3):

The function $p(t,x)$ in the Fokker-Planck equation is the probability density at time $t$ of the process $X_t$: $P(X_t \in A) = \int_A p(t, x)dx.$ In general, the evolution equation for the density of a Feller process (i.e. a "nice" Markov process) is
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}p(t,x) = \mathcal{L}^* p(t,x),\tag{1}$$
where $\mathcal{L}^*$ is the adjoint of the infinitesimal generator (equation 4.23 on p. 49 of the lecture notes you linked).

(Aside: To make (1) plausible, I find it helpful to remember that $\pi$ is an invariant distribution for a Markov chain if $P^T \pi = \pi$, where $\pi$ is a column vector and $P$ is a transition matrix, or $(P^T - I)\pi = 0$. The analogy to continuous time is $\mathcal{L}^* = P^T - I$, and $\partial_t p(t,x) = 0$. See also (4.21) in your lecture notes and the paragraph that precedes it.)

Here are the key calculations. The infinitesimal generator $\mathcal{L}$ of a Feller process $X_t$ is defined by
$$\mathcal{L}f(x) = \lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{E_x[f(X_t)] - f(x)}{t}$$
for a suitable class of functions $f$. To compute the infinitesimal generator of your diffusion, you can apply Itô's lemma and compute $E_x[f(X_t)]$ directly. For heuristics, you can Taylor expand (in one dimension for simplicity)
\begin{align*}
E_x[f(X_t)] &\approx E_x[f(x) + f'(x) (X_t - X_0) + (1/2) f''(x) (X_t - X_0)^2] \\
&= f(x) + f'(x)(-V'(x)t)+(1/2)f''(x)(2Dt),
\end{align*}
because for your diffusion the "mean" displacement for time $t$ starting at $x$ is $-V'(x)t$ and the "variance" is $(\sqrt{2Dt})^2 = 2Dt$.

The adjoint operator $\mathcal{L}^*$ is defined through the $L^2$ inner product: for any "nice" functions $f,g$, $\langle f, \mathcal{L}^* g\rangle = \langle \mathcal{L} f, g\rangle$. This is typically computed using integration by parts. This calculation is done in one dimension for $V(x)=x^2/2$ on p. 52, Example 4.7.3. of your lecture notes.

Comment: I did see this approach but this needs believing the identity $P_t^* = e^{L^* t}$ and that seems to need a separate proof to be given. Is there a formal proof of this? 

Is there an approach to get FPS from the SDE which avoids this infinitesimal generator?

Comment: The expression $P_t^* = e^{L^* t}$ is formal and is not used in the derivation of the Kolmogorov forward equation (the general name for the evolution of the density). One way or another, to write down the differential equation, you will need to write down the right differential operator.

Comment: Also if you start from a given SDE where $\mu$ is the distribution at say $X_0$ how do you prove that $P_t^*\mu$ is the distribution of $X_t$?

Comment: If you see equation 4.21, the derivation explicitly needed the identity that $u_t = P_t(f) = e^{Lt}f$. This equation is critical for 4.21 PDE to be derived.

Comment: Look at Section 5.2.2 "The Forward Kolmogorov Equation"; there is no use of the formal expression $e^{t L}$ in deriving the forward equation. If you want a rigorous approach to Markov proceses, you can consider a more advanced book like Karatzas and Shreve (it is a demanding book). I think this is all the help I can provide.

Comment: The problem with section 5.2.2 is that it starts from the assumptions given in Definitions 5.1.1 on page 53. Its a very different starting point than being given a SDE.